# 301 redirect using .htaccess for a php file

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

We had a website redesign and some of the pages no longer exist. I did 301 redirects on most of the old pages, but rather than have all of those old pages still in my folders I wanted to redirect everything in the .htaccess file instead. Below is my whole .htaccess file as of right now. The redirect of an html file to a php file works fine, but trying to redirect from a php file to a php file is not working. I have tried leaving the first part of the url (up to the .com) off of the new page but I still get a 404 error.  I have tried multiple other pages and get the same results every time, directing from html to php works but from php to php doesn't. Any suggestions?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /folder1/page1.php http://www.example.com/folder2/page2.php
Redirect 301 /folder1/page1.html http://www.example.com/folder2/page2.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 folder1/(.*) folder2/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Edit:

[RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) takes everything in folder1 and redirects to folder2

[RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) then takes all html file extensions and rewrites them to php

Comment: soudln't it be `RedirectMatch 301 folder1/(.*) folder2/$1` ?

Comment: Sorry, I am a novice, can you please explain what all of that means?

Comment: I don't want everything from folder 1 directed to folder 2, nor do I want all html files on my site rewritten to php. Is there another way?

Comment: Then I guess I misunderstood your question.  Are you only trying to redirect those two URLs?

Comment: Then you just have to make a reriteCond ... like that : `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.html)$`

Comment: I have a bunch of pages, maybe 100, that I need to do a 301 redirect for. We were hoping that we didn't have to, but we continue to get a bunch of 404 errors. Like I said, I already made a page for almost all of them with the following code:  <?php // Permanent 301 Redirect via PHP
header ("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header ("Location: http://www.example.com/products/10a.php");
exit();
?>

Comment: But all of these files are cluttering things up. I was hoping to add all of the redirects I want to a .htaccess file and make things a little cleaner. I can make redirects for html to php and pdf to pdf or pdf to php work but when I try to redirect a php to php it doesn't work.

Comment: Unless there's some commonality between the maybe 100 pages, you're probably stuck with doing the 301 redirects like you have been.  Which should work, but I'd have to see an example to know why it's not.  Anyway, maybe this will help - it's a bulk 301 redirect generator:
https://donatstudios.com/RewriteRule_Generator